# The use of $watch in directive

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I've rendered a chart using highchart.js using solutions from a couple questions. I understand the basic use of directives. However, in the case of highchart.js, I don't quite understand this code here:

```
app.directive('highchart', function () {
    var direc = {};
    var link = function (scope, element, attributes) {
        scope.$watch(function () {
            return attributes.chart;
        }, function () {
            var charts = JSON.parse(attributes.chart);
            $(element[0]).highcharts(charts);
        })
    }
    direc.restrict = 'E';
    direc.link = link;
    direc.template = '<div></div>';
    //the replace method replaces the content inside the element it is called
    direc.replace = true;
    direc.scope = {};
    return direc;
})
```

The charts attribute will accept a JSON array of chart attributes.

Can someone explain what's happening inside the function? Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $watch is used to monitor the changes on a specific field. In the above case the attributes.chart is being watched for changes in the first argument in the $watch function and the second argument works with actually checking the modified data and performing manipulation on it. 
You can also find further options that can be used by the $watch in the official angular docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch

Comment: So with respect to this post, if there is any changes to the attributes.chart, it will call the next function to evaluate the change to the attributes.chart value?

Answer (score 0):

$watch monitor the model chnanges, once the model chnages , updated values get from below code and as per requirement, required action can perform.

$scope.$watch('ng-model-name', function (newval, oldval) { 
                    if (newval< 0) {
                        `$('#modelCustomer').modal('show');`
                    }
                });